# Is there away with discord.js to make your script store the arg of a command and store it in a file

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I currently am trying to find a place that numbers (the args) of command on to a separate file, not sure what type of file works best, I assume JSON tho. I want to be able to then, later on, takes these numbers from said file to use them in another command for example -

1. Stores that the number "500" and "200" were typed into the command
2. Adds them together and gives a total of "700"

I hope someone gets what I mean and can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using node.js, You can use the [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) method, which takes a file path and a string and writes to a file.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const args = ["arg1", "arg2", 1, 5, true];
fs.writeFileSync("args.json", args.toString())
//in a function
function someFunction(some, args, here) {
  //...
  fs.writeFileSync(`args.json`, arguments.toString())
}
```

Comment: Even if this code snippet solves the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.